# Use a modal with ID

Tags: html, symfony, modal-dialog

I want to pop a modal of a category I want to give the ID of that category so I can give the corresponding TOS with it. I have the code the only problem is that I get a grey are and the modal itself doesn't load, here is my code:

```
 <div class="hiddenCategories" style="display: none" id="category{{category.id}}">
{%if category.getProvider%}<p>{{ 'webstoresettings.warning'|trans}}</p>{%endif%}
 <p>{{category.getShortTermsOfService}}</p> 
<p>

<p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="tos{{category.id}}" />
    <label for="tos{{category.id}}">{{ 'webstoresettings.confirm'|trans}} <a href="#modal" data-target="modal"class="modal-trigger">{{ 'webstoresettings.tos'|trans}}</a> (click to read)</label>
</p>

<!-- <input type="checkbox" id="{{category.id}}" /> -->

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div name="modal" id="modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>{{ 'webstoresettings.tos'|trans}}</h4>
        <p>{{category.getTermsOfService}}</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Ok</a>
    </div>
</div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I myself thought that the reference to the Modal was wrong. However that was not is

```
<div name="modal" id="modal" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
    <h4>{{ 'webstoresettings.tos'|trans}}</h4>
    <p>{{category.getTermsOfService}}</p> 
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Ok</a>
</div>
```

should have been changed to

```
<div name="modal{{category.id}}" id="modal{{category.id}}" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
    <h4>{{ 'webstoresettings.tos'|trans}}</h4>
    <p>{{category.getTermsOfService}}</p> 
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Ok</a>
</div>
```